# Linux Audio Sub Systems

Tags: linux, audio

I want to know about Linux audio, i spent a lot of time on reading but i didn't understand(clearly). Can anybody give a brief information on various Linux audio sub systems(Like OSS, ALSA, JACK, Gstreamer, Phonon, Xine)?.
Any help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: GStreamer is not a separate audio subsystem. It's "just" a media streaming framework that happens to be able to output to ALSA, JACK, OSS, and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once wrote a famous blog post about the jungle of Linux audio output formats. [You can find it here](http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2007/05/welcome_to_the_jungle.html).

Regrettably, the picture is no longer there, here's a copy:

[image: Jungle of Linux audio output formats]

It's a bit old (dating from 2007), but I hope it gives you the general idea. OSS and ALSA are the layers closest to the actual audio hardware. All the other libraries and frameworks simply talk to those lower layers. And as you can see, some of these libs and frameworks actually have wrappers around other libs and frameworks.

Which layer you want to call upon depends largely on what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Refer this link: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/sound/index.html